# FIle doesn't get updated by appending text in PHP

Tags: php, file, append, fwrite

I'm trying to append text with PHP to my text file, but `123.txt` is still empty after the code execution.

**Code:**

```
<?php
$fp = fopen('123.txt', "a+");
fwrite($fp, 'Cats chase dogs');
fclose($fp);
?>
```

I don't see anything wrong and I don't understand why it's not writing.

Any kind of help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Try `file_put_contents` instead:  https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php

Answer (score 0):

Before writing to a file using file handler you can check whether it is writable or exist.

```
<?php

$file = '123.txt';
if( file_exists( $file ) ){
    if( is_writable( $file )){
        $fp = fopen( $file, "a+");
        fwrite($fp, 'Cats chase dogs');
        fclose($fp);
    }else{
        echo 'file is not writable, check permission';
    }
   
}else{
    echo 'file does not exist';
}

?>
```

Also if you are on development then switch on the error reporting mode of php from php.ini file to know the error.